# Drag and drop, leer contenido del archivo

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

Hola estoy haciendo una pagina con drag and drop, necesito que al soltar el archivo en el area gris, pueda saber el contenido que lo puse en un array e imprimirlo en la consola, solo si es de texto

Este es el código que hice, si lo hago con input file funciona pero con drag and drop no puedo leer el contenido

Otra pregunta en drag and drop ¿hay alguna forma de que solo acepte un archivo a la vez?

```
     function permitirSoltar(e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
         e.preventDefault();
         var d=e.target;

         if (d.id ==="destino") {
             

             e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';

         }else{

             e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';
         }
     }

     function soltar(e){
         e.stopPropagation();
         e.preventDefault();
         var archivo=e.dataTransfer.files;
     
         leerArchivo(e,archivo);
     
     }

     function leerArchivo(e,archivo){
         
         if(!archivo){
             alert('No se selecciono ningun archivo');
         }
         var lector = new FileReader();
         lector.onload = function(e){
             var contenido=e.target.result;
             
         };
         lector.readAsText(archivo);

         console.log(contenido);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

tengo la sospecha de que enrealidad el porque de que no te funcionara es porque estabas tratando de leer una lista completa de archivos de una sola vez con el `FileReader`, es decir, checa esto que hiciste:

Primero en la funcion soltar haces esto:

```
var archivo=e.dataTransfer.files;
leerArchivo(e,archivo);
```

El tema es que `e.dataTransfer.files` te retorna un objeto `FileList` y no directamente un arreglo normal, esto pasa asi sea un solo archivo, por ende cuando tu haces:

```
lector.readAsText(archivo);
```

En tu otra funcion, esta mal, pues se supone que `FileReader` acepta ya sea un tipo `Blob` o un tipo `File`, no un `FileList`. por ende lo que debiste haber hecho es recorrer el `FileList` y ejecutar la lectura por cada uno de los archivos contenidos en el `FileList`.

Muy bien, corrigiendo este problema me ayude de esta pagina de aqui:

[Drag & Drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop/drag_and_drop_archivo)

La cual nos especifica muy claramente y de manera muy detallada todo lo que debes hacer para usar el sistema `drag & drop`, por ende cree un ejemplo tomando en cuenta tu funcion `leerArchivo` que tu hiciste, lo unico es que la modifique por lo que te comente antes:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

  const dragArea = document.getElementById("drag_area");

  function dropHandler(ev) {

    // Evitar el comportamiendo por defecto (Evitar que el fichero se abra/ejecute)
    ev.preventDefault();
    const files = [];

    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
      // Usar la interfaz DataTransferItemList para acceder a el/los archivos)
      for (let i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
        // Si los elementos arrastrados no son ficheros, rechazarlos
        if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
          files.push(ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile());
        }
      }
    } else {
      // Usar la interfaz DataTransfer para acceder a el/los archivos
      for (let i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
        files.push(ev.dataTransfer.files[i]);
      }
    }
    
    //Llamamos a la funcion que se encarga de leer los archivos
    leerArchivo(files);

    // Pasar el evento a removeDragData para limpiar
    removeDragData(ev)
  }
  
  function removeDragData(ev) {
    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
      // Use DataTransferItemList interface to remove the drag data
      ev.dataTransfer.items.clear();
    } else {
      // Use DataTransfer interface to remove the drag data
      ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
    }
  }
  
  function dragOverHandler(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
  
  function leerArchivo(archivos){
      
      if(!archivos) alert('No se selecciono ningun archivo');
      
      archivos.forEach(archivo =>{
        const lector = new FileReader();
      
        lector.onload = e =>{
          let contenido = e.target.result;
          console.log(contenido);
        };

        lector.readAsText(archivo);
      });
  }
  
  dragArea.addEventListener("drop", dropHandler);
  dragArea.addEventListener("dragover", dragOverHandler);

}
```

```css
.drag_area{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: grey;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
}

.drag_area > p{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class = "drag_area" id = "drag_area">
  <p>Arrastre archivos aqui...</p>
</div>
```

**NOTA**: La mayor parte del codigo fue sacada de la pagina, yo lo unico que hice fue adaptarlo para que coincida con `ES6` y quitarle lineas innecesarias.

Comment: Posdata, con respecto a tu pregunta de que si es posible que solo se acepte un archivo por vez, creo que esto no es posible de manera directa nediante `drag & drop`, pero lo bueno es que esto aun puede controlarse colocando una simple condicion, por ejemplo, antes de intentar leer los archivos en tu funcion `leerArchivo` puedes comprobar en la funcion `dropHandler` si hay mas de un archivo, en cuyo caso no ejecutarias la funcion `leerArchivo` si no que simplemente le muestras un `alert` al usuario diciendole que solo se puede subir un archivo a la vez por ej.